# Getting Error while calling a UDF function with function name having special character ampersand in NAGIOS

Tags: sql-server

While calling a UDF function in **NAGIOS** with function name containing **ampersand** '&', It returns an error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The multi-part
>   identifier "dbo.udf_tarrif_t&TT" could not be bound

Comment: Who creates a function with an `&` in the name? That's begging for problems...

Comment: @Sven, So you mean to say '&' is responsible for this problem? nagios do not accept special character?

Answer (score 0):

In NAGIOS while calling a function with a Function name containing any special character, It returns an error because NAGIOS does not take any special character as input.